# Переменные повышенной точности

Tags: c, c++

Может кто-нибудь подсказать библиотеки для С и/или С++ для работы с real-type переменными повышенной или фиксированной точности? Пока нашел только quadmath в составе gcc.

**P.S.** Будет особенно приветствоваться доступность на Linux

Comment: что именно имеется ввиду? что то точнее Double?

Comment: @KoVadim, именно так

Comment: если не хватает мантисы, то решение простое - перейти к целочисленной арифметике. Есть ещё встроенный тип logn double.
Правда, зачем такая точность - для меня загадка.

Comment: У long double на x86 по-моему точность 80 бит.

Comment: А вот в VS 2010 к сожалению по 8 байт.
std::cout << "\nразмер double=" << sizeof(double);
std::cout << "\nразмер long double=" << sizeof(long double);

Answer (score 5):

GMP и mpir.
Одна для 32 вторая для 64.

Это в принципе одна и та же библиотека. Все функции идентичны, mpir написали позже для поддержки 64 архитектуры.

Подключал так.

```
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
#if _WIN64
#define ENVIRONMENT64
#ifndef __GMP_H__
#include <mpir.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"mpir.lib")
#endif
#else
#define ENVIRONMENT32
#ifndef __GMP_H__
#include <gmp-static/gmp.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"gmp.lib")
#endif
#endif
#endif

mpf_t число;
int точность = 200;

std::string значение = "5.10003000000000000000111111111111111";

// установка точности свыше 1000 будет тормозить
mpf_set_default_prec(точность);
// инициализация с присваиванием
mpf_init_set_str (число , значение.data() , 0);

// получить int
int значение1 = mpf_get_si(число);
// получить double
double значение2 = mpf_get_d(число);
std::cout << "\nзначение2=" << значение2;
```

Только тестировал под windows. Могу скинуть примерчик. Но не знаю сколько по времени займёт, так как для себя писал обёртку на русском.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.